# $_GET["_url"] on Apache2 Webserver not working

Tags: php, xampp, apache2

I am currently working on a REST API in PHP. Therefore I set up XAMPP on my Windows 10 PC and so far it is working as intended.

To access a REST-Endpoint I would have to open `https://<PC IP>/Api/ExampleEndpoint`. Now `ExampleEndpoint` is saved in the Variable `$_GET["_url"]` and i can see the Content of that Endpoint in my Browser.

Now i tried the same on an Apache2 Webserver on my Raspberry PI, but when accessing the same Endpoint in the Browser (`https://<RASP-IP>/Api/ExampleEndpoint`) i get an *404 Not Found - The requested URL /Api/server was not found on this server.* If i explicitly provide the Parameter as a GET Variable in the URL (`https://<RASP-IP>/Api?_url=ExampleEndpoint`) it works as intended.

Is there a possibility to use the same URL Syntax as it worked for XAMPP on Windows?

---

- PC: Win10, XAMPP, PHP7.3.3
- Raspberry PI: Debian Stretch, Apache2 Webserver, PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u3

Comment: "Now ExampleEndpoint is saved in the Variable $_GET["_url"]" <- how? I'm guessing some url rewriting, if so please provide details about it. I'm guessing they're not loading on your Raspberry PI setup.

Comment: @Jeto It is probably a built in rewrite of XAMPP, i didn't write any rewrite Rules. Thanks for the hint, I will look it up